# Loop through posts and filter all cities where state is specified

Tags: jekyll

Given a number of markdown files within an `offices` folder, I need to loop through each one and find/render the city value where the state is a given value. So far I have this, but it renders every city regardless of the where clause:

```
<ul class="cities">
{% for post in site.offices | where: "state", "florida" %}
  <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

`<li>{{ post.title }}</li` should list all of the cities from the markdown files that have Florida as their state.

This is a sample markdown file:

```
---
office_id: 5
title: Orlando
state: florida
phone: 123-456-7890
---
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that I had to set an assignment first:

```
{% assign cities = (site.offices | where: "state" , "florida") %}
  {% for city in cities %}
    <li>{{ city.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
```